# JSF2 lifecycle and built-in validation

Tags: jsf-2

In JSF2 application at which phase the built-in validations will get executed? Any help on this would really appreciated.

Comment: This is a classic interview question which can easily be answered by just looking in [the specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's a [Process Validations](http://www.java-tutorial.ch/java-server-faces/jsf-2-lifecycle#process_validations) phase. It occurs after Restore View and Apply Request so the JSF can process all attached validators and check value of components.